# iOS-Slide-Menu. When popping a viewController, buttons on present viewController not working anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the iOS-Slide-Menu pod of aryaxt. In my project, the whole library is working as expected apart from one thing. I have a start view A in my SlideNavigationController that contains a button. When tapping on the button, it'll push viewController B. In the menu, I have a button that does exactly the same thing, pushing viewController B on top of A.

Scenario 1:
App starts, A appers. I tap on the button of viewController A and viewController B will be pushed. When tapping on Back, B will be popped and viewController A is present. When tapping the button, B gets pushed and so forth. Everything working fine.

Scenario 2:
App starts, A appears. I select the menu and tap the menu-button that pushes B. Works fine. When tapping on Back, viewController A appears. Now when I tap the button of viewController A, nothing happens. The button just won't do anything. Funny thing is... when I slide the menu out and in, the button works again.

In scenario 2, I use the following code to push the viewController:

```
[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToRootAndSwitchToViewController:vc
                                                         withSlideOutAnimation:self.slideOutAnimationEnabled
                                                                 andCompletion:nil];
```

This is causing the effect, just described.

When using simply `[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] pushViewController:vc animated:NO];`
 instead of the code above the whole thing is working just fine.

In scenario 1, I only have a push segue from button to viewController B in InterfaceBuilder.

I really have no idea what the problem is, as I have basically the same configuration like the example project on https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

Any help is highly appreciated.